# Using a for loop to populate a database to test mongoose.js with Supertest, sometimes all the test documents aren't created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

Using mocha I built a loop and during each iteration 10 documents are created. However, I test each iteration for 10 documents in the collection and sometimes there are 7 or 9. It just skips writing some and moves onto the next iteration. I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
'use strict';

// Load the test dependencies
var app = require('../../server.js'),
    request = require('supertest'),
    should = require('should'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Booking = mongoose.model('Booking');

// create a 'booking' test suite
describe('Battles controller tests:', function() {

    describe('testing to see if controller is wired', function() {
        it('should respond with 200', function(done) {
            request(app)
                .get('/api/battles')
                .expect(200)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    done();
                });
        })
    });

    for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
        describe('for some reason it\'s not saving 10 entries to mongodb' + i, function() {
            before(function(done) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    var booking = new Booking({
                        name: 'Name' + i
                    });

                    booking.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) throw new Error('Booking didn\'t save');
                    });
                }

                done();
            });

            after(function(done) {
                Booking.remove(function() {
                    done();
                });
            });

            it('should have 10 bookings in database', function(done) {
                Booking.find({}, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) done(err);
                    res.should.be.an.Array.and.have.lengthOf(10);
                    done();
                })
            });
        })
    }
    describe.skip('two bookings should be returned from a GET request', function() {
        before(function(done) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                var booking = new Booking({
                    name: 'Name' + i
                });

                booking.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) throw new Error('Booking didn\'t save');
                });
            }

            done();
        });

        after(function(done) {
            Booking.remove(function() {
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should have 10 bookings in database', function(done) {
           Booking.find({}, function(err, res) {
               if (err) done(err);
               res.should.be.an.Array.and.have.lengthOf(10);
               done();
           })
        });

        it('a battle should have two bookings', function(done) {
            request(app)
                .get('/api/battles')
                .expect(200)
                .end(function (err, bookings) {
                    if (err) throw new Error('Shit exploded');
                    bookings.body.should.be.an.Array.and.have.lengthOf(2);
                    done();
                })
        });

    });

    describe('testing api for battles including GET, UPDATE', function() {
        describe('GET two bookings', function() {
            it('should have two random bookings');
            it('should have two different bookings');
        });

        describe('UPDATE two bookings after battle', function() {
            it('should have a winner and a loser');
            it('should ')
        });
    });


});
```

The console output is:

```
for some reason it's not saving 10 entries to mongodb96
  ✓ should have 10 bookings in database
for some reason it's not saving 10 entries to mongodb97
  ✓ should have 10 bookings in database
for some reason it's not saving 10 entries to mongodb98
  ✓ should have 10 bookings in database
for some reason it's not saving 10 entries to mongodb99
  ✓ should have 10 bookings in database
two bookings should be returned from a GET request
  ✓ should have 10 bookings in database


GET /api/battles 200 2.437 ms - 284
      ✓ a battle should have two bookings
    testing api for battles including GET, UPDATE
      GET two bookings
        - should have two random bookings
        - should have two different bookings
      UPDATE two bookings after battle
        - should have a winner and a loser
        - should 
  102 passing (765ms)
  4 pending
  1 failing

  1) Battles controller tests: for some reason it's not saving 10 entries to mongodb19 should have 10 bookings in database:
     Uncaught AssertionError: expected [  name: 'Name1',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b04272,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.8592369803227484, 0.0753506247419864 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 },
  name: 'Name2',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b04273,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.3049920208286494, 0.6233754165004939 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 },
  name: 'Name3',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b04274,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.8182909155730158, 0.8650113325566053 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 },
  name: 'Name4',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b04275,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.5385263541247696, 0.8532190786208957 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 },
  name: 'Name5',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b04276,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.06912864232435822, 0.6825810072477907 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 },
  name: 'Name9',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b0427a,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.26058629737235606, 0.34282937669195235 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 },
  name: 'Name7',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b04278,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.9167483656201512, 0.831106147961691 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 },
  name: 'Name8',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b04279,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.1588533204048872, 0.6727582819294184 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 },
  name: 'Name6',
   _id: 55b429c4191a0b6666b04277,
   __v: 0,
   random: [ 0.2860944678541273, 0.1905197137966752 ],
   losses: 0,
   wins: 0,
   rating: 1000 } ] to have property length of 10 (got 9)
      at Promise.<anonymous> (app/tests/battles.server.controller.test.js:51:53)



adam@mastera:/var/www/html/mean$
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an async problem. Mongodb has the documents queued to be saved but the done() function is called in mocha moving on to the it() test before mongodb saved all the documents.

Instead of the model.save(callback(err)) function, I'm using the Model.create([], callback) method in mongoose and passing the done() function into the callback so it waits for mongodb to finish saving everything before running the test.

```
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        describe('for some reason it\'s not saving 10 entries to mongodb' + i, function() {
            before(function(done) {

                var names = [];

                for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                    names.push({name: 'name' + i});
                }

                Booking.create(names, function(err, bookings) {
                    if (err) done(err);
                    done();
                })

            });

            after(function(done) {
                Booking.remove(function() {
                    done();
                });
            });

            it('should have 10 bookings in database', function(done) {
                Booking.find({}, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) done(err);
                    res.should.be.an.Array.and.have.lengthOf(100);
                    done();
                });
            });
        });
    }
```